# ClassLoader.getResource() doesn't work from .jar file

Tags: java, image, jar

I have the following code:

```
private final ImageIcon placeHolder = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Cards\\trans.png"));
```

But this does not work once my application exported into a `.jar` file.

Comment: Does not work how? You get an exception? It does not render? Please, be more specific

Comment: Classmate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662686/images-will-not-work-in-a-jar-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127/java-swing-displaying-images-from-within-a-jar  , as posted by jjnguy in the question linked to by BalusC

Answer (score 10):

Your "\t" is being compiled as a tab - you need to escape it:

```
private final ImageIcon placeHolder = new ImageIcon(
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Cards\\trans.png"));
```

Note the double backslash. This may not be the only thing wrong, of course - but it's a start...

In fact, I would specify it with a forward slash instead. That works on both Windows and Unix-based OSes anyway, and it also works with jar files. The only reason I highlighted the double backslash was to raise the point of string escaping in general. Try this:

```
private final ImageIcon placeHolder = new ImageIcon(
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Cards/trans.png"));
```

Next, make sure you've got the *exact* correct name for the file, including case. Even though Windows file systems aren't generally case-sensitive, jar files are. If it's actually "cards" instead of "Cards" or "TRANS.png" instead of "trans.png", it won't work.

Comment: Is there a reason you call getResource on the ClassLoader instead of just the class? (i.e. won't getClass().getResource() work? )

Comment: @JRL: If you call it from the classloader it's relative to the root of the jar file rather than to the class. You can use a leading slash to get the same effect from a call to Class.getResource though.

Answer (score 4):

Use this for getting images in jar file

`ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/Springz3.png"));`

Comment: oh. em.  gee.  You have no idea how long I was looking for this answer.  Everybody keeps saying to use getResource(..), but that doesn't work for images/sounds in a jar file!  You have to use getSystemResource(..)!!!!!  Thanks a ton for this answer!

Comment: No mention please.