# getResourceAsStream() called by abstract class returning null

Tags: java, jar, abstract-class, getresource

※ I have looked at the old questions and none fixed my problem.

I am having an issue of `getResourceAsStream` returning `null`. It works in Eclipse but not when I use the project as a jar file.

The jar file has a folder name `config` and in the folder config, there is a `config file`. I try to import the config file using the code below.

```
file = "/" + new File(configFolder, configFileName).getPath();
in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

The jar worked before. But now that I changed my codes and put the code above in an abstract class. It isn't working. getResourceAsStream is returning null.

I tried `MyAbstractClass.class.getResourceAsStream(file)` but still it isn't working.

Comment: Do you have more than one JAR?

Comment: Print out `file`. Make sure it really points to an existing file inside of the JAR.

Comment: I had only one jar. Printing file gives "/config\configfilename.txt". Do I need to use "/"?

Comment: get rid off the backslash, yes. Don't use File to construct the path. Just concatenate the Strings.

Comment: Thank you. I changed to string concatenation and it is working now.  Could you please add this into your answer so I could accept it? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassLoader.getResource() doesn't work from .jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664073/classloader-getresource-doesnt-work-from-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

You are running into class loader issues. Use `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);`

If it still doesn't work, there's probably something wrong with your class path or the resource path.

Comment: This works for me, thanks Jilles! For the sake of completeness only, `MyAbstractClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(relativePath);` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Standard lone java applications, backslash could not be work for load the property file(config file). But it will work in web applications with backslash.