# Creating a Jar - Getting blank screen

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a game and i wanted to create a jar. So i used Fat Jar Eclipse Plugin to create one http://fjep.sourceforge.net/

However, When i open it up, i just see a blank screen. 
To get my images im using commands like

`new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Images/MainMenu/MainMenuButton_1.PNG"`

So im am unsure why it is not working.

Edit: I figured out that it works if it is in the same directory as my project
How to i get it so it doesnt have to be

Comment: Do you have any hard-coded file-paths?  Are you using any other resources in your project directory?

Comment: [Duplicate] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662686/images-will-not-work-in-a-jar-file) , easily found with the search. Please search a little before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour described is consistent with the load thread exiting due to an uncaught FileNotFoundException, before having add anything to the pane shown.

I can strongly recommend printing out `file.getAbsolutePath()` when you encounter FileNotFoundExceptions as that information is not present in the exception message.  This will help you find out why the file name was broken.