# Read a file from a jar file, the jar generated using netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have a java project which should read file in a external folder. I give the file path as '../FolderName' in the class. But if I generated a jar file from this project, it cannot read the file. What is the correct way to define the folder path in this kind of situations ?

Comment: You can provide some code you have written so far, the name of the jar, and maybe a location inside the project or filesystem. Do you have problems with other jars/zips, or only with those built in netbeans?

Comment: [Load Icon Image Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9864267/1393766) <- rule applies to all resources, not only images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to pass the absolute path to your code (jar) as program argument.

```
java -jar myjar.jar abs_path
```

You can then access the absolute path in the main() method of your class (mentioned in the `manifest.mf` file of a JAR) as follows:

```
String filePath = args[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`.

It reads the file from inside your `JAR`.

Example:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/classpath/to/my/file");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

A good Reference : [How to read a file from a jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271926/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/classpath/toyourfile");
```