# How can I set the directory in which to look for a text file in my java application within a batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I tried searching for an answer to this but nothing I've found has worked.  I am trying to execute a java application from a batch file but can't get the application to pickup my input text file directory.  I'll illustrate what I mean.

In my java application, I have the following:

```
String myFile = System.getProperty("myfile");

System.err.println(myFile);
```

And in my batch application that is running the program I have:

```
set -Dmyfile="C:\directory"
```

However, when I actually run the program, it seems that `myfile` isn't being picked up as a system property because `null` is printed as the value of `myFile`.
Could anyone offer some help please?

Comment: what does the `-D` portion do in your `set` command line?? remove it and try again...

Comment: i dont think you need the `set` it would be `java -jar -Dmyfile="C:\directory" jarname.jar`

Comment: Thanks, I added the -D because several sites I looked at indicated that in order to set a variable as a system property, the -D was necessary.  Unfortunately, removing it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Hi J. Con, thanks for the response, if I were to use the syntax you indicated might work, would I need to store the text file in a jar?

Comment: You just asked how to get a system property via code which was set by command line arguments. Are you trying to read the actual text file? because that is a lot different

Comment: What does your batch file look like? Perhaps you are missing the parameter passing into it. If your batch looks like `java -jar jarname.jar` you should add `java %1 -jar jarname.jar` to echo the first command-line arg given to the batch file within what the batch file executes.

Comment: Hi J.Con, please let me know if this clarifies it.  In my java code, I read a text file whose directory I store in myFile.  The only thing I am trying to pass to the java code is the directory of this file via the batch.  Alternatively I could just set String myFile = "C:\\directory" but I want to have single click execution of my program via a batch file.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271926/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-jar-file hopefully that will point you in the right direction

Comment: To set a system property through a batch file you have to do: `set myfile = "c:\directory"` the -D is a parameter to set variables to the jvm.