# How to bundle images in jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I made a java application.and bundled all classes in jar file..wen i run the project from netbeans  my app is running successfully..but wen i place my .jar file at another place and run from there..i am not getting the icons used by my application..In the code i get my icons from images directory present in project folder.

Now,i wanted to know how can we present these image files to the end user (like we present .jar file).Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at my answer here [For adding images and icons in JAR files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42084902/7199218) in swing components.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems like there are two questions here:

1. How do I get NetBeans to include an image file in the jar produced when I build my project?
2. How do I access an image file from a jar?

This answer applies to NetBeans 6.8 and addresses both of the subquestions.

Assume that you have an ant based Java Application Project.

Here is the 'Files' view of the project

```
JP
+ images
  + test.jpg
+ nbproject
+ src
  + jp
    + Main.java
+ test
+ build.xml
+ manifest.mf
```

Inside your Main.java you have code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // find the file in the file system.. probably not a good idea
    File f = new File("images/test.jpg");
    System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath()+" "+f.exists());
```

When you run this project from inside NB you get this output:

```
/export/home/vkraemer/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/images/test.jpg true
```

When you run the code packed into the jar, you get something like this:

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/export/home/vkraemer/nbhg/web-main
bash-3.2$ java -jar /export/home/vkraemer/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/dist/JavaApplication2.jar
/export/home/vkraemer/nbhg/web-main/images/test.txt false
```

To get something better when the jar is executed, you need to do the following:

**Add the images directory as a source root for you project**.

Right click on the project and select the Properties item. A dialog will appear.

Select 'Sources' in the list that is on the left side of the dialog. This will change the content of the panel on the right side of the dialog.

Press the 'Add Folder...' button that appears next to the 'Source Package Folders' table. A FileChooser will appear.

Use this chooser to select the images folder and press the OK button. An entry for the images folder will be added table.

Use the OK button on the Project Properties dialog to accept the changes and dismiss the dialog.

**Change your code to use [Class.getResource()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // find the file in the file system.. probably not a good idea
    File f = new File("images/test.jpg");
    System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath()+" "+f.exists());
    URL url = Main.class.getResource("/test.jpg");
    System.out.println(url);
```

When you run the project from inside the IDE, you should see something like this:

```
/export/home/vkraemer/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/images/test.jpg true
file:/export/home/vkraemer/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/images/test.jpg
```

When you run the code packed into the jar, you will get something like this:

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/export/home/vkraemer/nbhg/web-main
bash-3.2$ java -jar /export/home/vkraemer/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/dist/JavaApplication2.jar
/export/home/vkraemer/nbhg/web-main/images/test.jpg false
jar:file:/export/home/vkraemer/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/dist/JavaApplication2.jar!/test.jpg
```

After you get the URL for the test.jpg file, you can use [ImageIcon(URL)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.net.URL%29) to create the icon

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was having a similar problem with referencing image resources from .exe java application wrapper. With your solution, however, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

For a Maven Project in NetBeans 6.9, put your filen into Resources in the "Other Sources" folder of the Project.

And be sure you dont forget the leading "/"