# Add images to jar

Tags: java, jar

I want to set icon to my JFrame. I do the following:

```
Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/images/icon.jpg");
this.setIconImage(icon);
```

It works fine when I run this code from netbeans, but when I try to run this code from jar file, images are not shown in my JFrame. I have tried to load images as resources:

```
this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/src/images/icon.jpg")));
```

but when I run this code it fails with `NullPointerException`

```
 Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:99)
        at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:113)
        at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:240)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
        at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
```

How can I do this work?

**edit:**
Thanks to all,
the problem  was solved by specifying image as

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/icon.JPG"))
```

As for it seems rather weird, and would be better if it was like

```
this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(pathToIcon).getImage());
```

Comment: What is the structure of your JAR file i.e. where exactly in the JAR file is the image placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code of URLImageSource, it appears that the reason that `getConnection` throws an NPE is that it has a `null` for the url.  And that leads me to suspect that

```
getClass().getResource("/src/images/icon.jpg")
```

is returning `null`.  It would do that if it could not locate a resource with that pathname.

I bet that the problem is that you've got the path wrong.

To prove / disprove this, you should run `jar tvf` on the JAR file, and look for the line that matches `"icon.jpg"`.  Is the corresponding pathname the same as what you are using?  If not, use the pathname from the matching line in the `getResource` call and it should work.  Alternatively, if the file doesn't show up at all, look at the NetBeans build configs that tell it what to put in the JAR file.  (I'm not a NetBeans user, so I can't say where you would need to look ...)

---

If that leads you absolutely nowhere, another possibility is that `getClass().getResource(...)` is using a classloader that doesn't know about the JAR file containing the image.  (This seems pretty improbable to me ...)

Comment: jar tvf shows that icon.jpg is located in images/icon.jpg, but neither getClass().getResource("/images/icon.jpg") nor getClass().getResource("images/icon.jpg") doesn't work. But getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/icon.jpg") works fine.

Comment: I Have the same problem, but I am doing it inside of a main method, so "getClass()" doesn't work. what should I put instead of that? I tried creating a new instance of the main class, but that gave me an Exception when I tried it.

Comment: Try `YourMainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resourePath)`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your JAR file has a top level directory called `images`, you can use either:

1. `getClass().getResource("/images/icon.jpg")` or
2. `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/icon.jpg")`

Answer (score 2):

`getResource()` loads a resource from classpath, not an OS path, and the after compilation your classpath will not include the `/src` folder, but rather just its contents. So you'd better try `/images/icon.jpg`.

Also you may find [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273040/how-to-bundle-images-in-jar-file) somewhat useful.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it assuming you can import javax.imageio.ImageIO:

```
Image icon = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/src/images/icon.jpg"));
this.setIconImage(icon);
```

Comment: It can not find such file in specified location, but it is there

Comment: hmm..Can you try moving the image file to a folder outside, but at the same level as the src directory.  Like: "/resources/images/icon.jpg"?

Answer (score 0):

```
.."/src/images/icon.jpg"..
```

The '/src' prefix of the address seems suspicious.  Many apps. will provide separate 'src' and 'build' directories, but it normally ends up that the 'src' prefix is not used in the resulting Jar.  I recommend trying..

```
.."/images/icon.jpg"..
```

& also **triple** checking that the image is in the location of the Jar that the code is expecting to find it.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you should access the images from a directory relative to some fixed class. 
For example, if the image files are saved in a directory "images" on the same level as the `Toolkit.class`, then

`this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Toolkit.class.getResource("images/icon.jpg")));`

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a package inside the main source, and incluse your images in this package. Then, just call the images in your main class like:

`ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon(MainClass.class.getResource("/Package/Image.jpg"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Edit Configure File");
//Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/ctx.Icon"));
f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("images/ctx.PNG").getImage());//this works for me finally
//f.setIconImage(image);
//f.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("images/ctx.PNG")));
```