# Uncaught Error while fetching Image in exported jar

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

My Application uses some images.The application works fine in the Eclipse IDE.Here's the Code Snippet being used :

```
URL url=screen_one.class.getClassLoader().getResource("./small.png");

JLabel image=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url)));
```

But when i export it to a jar , it shows Uncaught error fetching Image.I think its related to the path of the image "small.png".

But when i run "jar tvf" with my file name this is the output -

1635 Tue Apr 03 19:53:44 IST 2012 small.png

This suggests the path is correct ; So,Where am i wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would put all images in the `/src/res` folder in order to make sure they are exported properly with your .jar.  Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273040/how-to-bundle-images-in-jar-file) similar question.

Comment: No, but I have had problems trying to do it that way.  Putting the images in /src/res and accessing them using "/res/icon.png" got it working for me.

Comment: Well Yeah,that works.Any reason as to why my earlier approach did not work?

Comment: That does not count as an explanation for this , i think?:-|

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10081/discussion-between-nikel-and-lrandroid)