# Exception When Running Exported Program, but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I am writing a program and am attempting to export it and send it to someone. When I run the program in Eclipse, it works perfectly well. However, when I export it as a Runnable JAR File and double-click it, it quits and tells me to check the console.

Here's the stack trace:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1275)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.util.PrereleaseChecker.run(PrereleaseChecker.java:29)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.AudioRPG.main(AudioRPG.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1275)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.window.Window.<init>(Window.java:62)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.window.WindowManager.setup(WindowManager.java:16)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.AudioRPG.main(AudioRPG.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

---

I think it didn't export the image correctly. Here's how I access the image:

```
BufferedImage myPicture = null;
try { myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("images/audiorpglogo.png")); }
catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
```

---

Also, when i try

`myPicture = ImageIO.read(Window.class.getResource("/images/audiorpglogo.png"));`

I get a stack trace, even when running within Eclipse:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1362)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.window.Window.<init>(Window.java:70)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.window.WindowManager.setup(WindowManager.java:16)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.AudioRPG.main(AudioRPG.java:29)
```

Comment: Go to command prompt/terminal, and run the program using `java -jar` syntax. Then you can see the exception output. Post that here.

Comment: How about showing us the exception / trace?

Comment: Well, good stacktrace. Unfortunately it tells us nothing about your code.

Comment: It says that it cannot load the image. I guess Eclipse didn't add the image to the jar file. `javax.imageio.ImageIO.read`

Comment: @PogoStick29 How are acessing the image file? Can you show us that code?

Comment: @PogoStick29 Yes, you're right, you need to add the image to the JAR for that to work.

Comment: Here's where the image is on Eclipse: http://icap.me/i/ji6RDiFPLI.png What do I need to do with it?

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273040/how-to-bundle-images-in-jar-file), for starters :P

Comment: @PogoStick29 YOu can use `Classname.class.getResource("Your file name")`. Make sure that you have that file in your class folder.

Comment: I tried `myPicture = ImageIO.read(Window.class.getResource("/images/audiorpglogo.png"));` but I got a stack trace `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`

Comment: @PogoStick29 If you want to use this then you have to move your image file into that class folder. and only you have to use `audiorpglogo.png`. However the answer given Pshemo was very correct. Much better than waht I am telling you.

Comment: Noob question, but by class folder do you mean the package in which the class resides?

Comment: @PogoStick29 Yes class folder where you have your files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/myimage.jpg");
```

this will work if you have `images/myimage.jpg` directory in the same folder that you are running your application with your JAR file.

---

or if you want to use image that is placed **inside** JAR file you can use

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/myimage.jpg"));
```

Don't be afraid when it wont work in IDE. It will work when you run it from JAR file.

---

Here is some code sample that works for me:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JLabel iconLabel;

    public MyFrame() throws IOException {

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                "images/myimage.jpg"));
        iconLabel = new JLabel(icon);
        getContentPane().add(iconLabel);

        setSize(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

When I try to run it in Eclipse I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
    at MyFrame.<init>(MyFrame.java:14)
    at MyFrame.main(MyFrame.java:25)
```

this Eclipse project looks like

[image]

After i export this project to JAR with `images` folder by

`right-click on project` -> `Export` -> `JAR file` -> `next`

[image]

`next` -> `next` -> `select main class`

[image]

I double-click created JAR file and see frame with my image:

[image]

Comment: I need the JAR to be self-contained. I tried something similar to the second idea you had (see code above), and it didn't work.

Comment: Here is where my image file is stored: http://icap.me/i/ItljCp3Z6c.png Here is how I attempt to access it: `myPicture = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/audiorpglogo.png"));` Here is the stack trace I get when exporting (as JAR file) and running with `java -jar`: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`

Comment: Would you like a copy of the code so you can try to make it work?

Comment: @PogoStick29 Do you have this error when you run it from IDE or from console?

Comment: I get the error when I run it form the console with `java -jar`

Comment: Are you sure your Jar file contains `images` directory? JARs are ZIP files so you can unzip them somewhere to check its content.

Comment: Here's what I get when I unzip: http://icap.me/i/wboY28Ixpo.png and here's what's inside the images folder: http://icap.me/i/RExTWBDbWs.png

Comment: Could you tell me if my sample project works for you? Maybe problem is in paths not in code. Maybe you need to add `./images` or something like that (not sure myself).

Comment: @PogoStick29 Could you instead of `BufferedImage` and `ImageIO.read` try to use just `logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/myimage.jpg")));`. Also make sure that after doing any change in code you are running the newest JAR file.

Comment: I am now using `logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/audiorpglogo.png")));`. The program quits without a stack trace or anything. (http://icap.me/i/kCHAWZFj5T.png)

Comment: @PogoStick29 Try to add these lines to your code `System.out.println("before using image"); logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/audiorpglogo.png"))); System.out.println("after using image");`. After you run your code if you see only `"before using image"` then it means that we still have problem with reading image, if you will also see `"after using image"` then it is probable that reading image worked. Also if you wont see any output in console then it means that your app crashed before this lines.

Comment: @PogoStick29 OK, I give up for today, I am too sleepy. Will try to help you tomorrow. Also maybe try to create and add to your question [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so others will be able to reproduce this unusual behavior on their computers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28163/discussion-between-pogostick29-and-pshemo)