# an exportet jar file won't access resources

Tags: java, jar, resources

When iv'e tried to open it it could'nt find the resources. 
So, I've already tried to use [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960747/exception-when-running-exported-program-but-not-in-eclipse) but i get another problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
problem: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
getClass() from the type Object
        at Resources.getMainBG(Resources.java:21)
        at Tetris.<init>(Tetris.java:21)
        at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

The current code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Resources 
{
    // this class import the breaks's photos into an image array named "images"
    private static Image[] images = new Image[7];
    private static Image[] BG = new Image[3]; // 1=frame,2=pane,3=nextPane


    public static Image getImage(int color){
        if(images[color]==null){
            try{images[color] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/block" + color + ".png")).getImage();}
            catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();System.exit(1);}}
        return images[color];}

    public static Image getMainBG() {
        if (BG[0] == null)
            BG[0] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/MainBG.png")).getImage();
        return BG[0];}

    public static Image getPaneBG(){
        if (BG[1] == null)
            BG[1] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/PaneBG.png")).getImage();
        return BG[1];}

    public static Image getNextBG() {
        if (BG[2] == null)
            BG[2] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/NextBG.png")).getImage();
        return BG[2];}
}
```

thank's a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception says it all - the code didn't even compile when you exported it. This method is invalid:

```
public static Image getMainBG() {
    if (BG[0] == null)
        BG[0] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/MainBG.png")).getImage();
    return BG[0];
}
```

You can't call `getClass()` unqualified like that in a static method. You could use `Resources.class` instead, of course.

Note that you shouldn't have got anywhere near as far as an exception though: you should check that your code compiles *before* you start packaging it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Image i = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/x.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the Exception. 
You should call

```
Resources.class.getResource(...)
```

instead of

```
getClass().getResource(...)
```