# Creating jar file of a Netbeans project containing external resources

Tags: java, exe, executable-jar

I have completed a Netbeans project. Now I want to create an executable .jar file (or any other executable) of this application. The project loads data from several text files and audio files for its execution.

It seems that I have to provide the user with these extra files along with the jar file. Is there any way to combine all the files in a single executable file?

Comment: Are you creating your jar using Maven or from the command line? In any case: it's easy to include resources in a jar file. Loading them from the jar file is a tad more difficult, but it's explained in many other answers to questions on Stack Overflow. See for instance: https://capturevision.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/how-to-embed-resource-files-using-netbeans/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bundle images in jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273040/how-to-bundle-images-in-jar-file)