# Compiled .Jar Crashes (no java console) but compiles and runs in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, libgdx, compiled

I am using Libgdx to code a game and it makes use of methods such as Gdx.files.internal("file") to load files, this should work when exporting the application since that is what it's meant to do

Some files are copied to the USER directory and loaded from there too (the audio) is this what is making the app crash? As mentioned here: [Java application runs properly in Eclipse, but not as .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618963/java-application-runs-properly-in-eclipse-but-not-as-jar)

If anyone could give me an idea as to whats going on that'd be great, it doesn't launch the java console for me either so I have no idea

The compiled .jar is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz9v7lkdsj78z20/RUSHmup.jar (With libraries inside too)

Heres the audio loading code which i THINK is causing the problem (but all i can see is stuff thats meant to work ok and DOES in Eclipse)

```
if(!Gdx.files.external("test.wav").exists()){
            String f = copySong(FILE);
        }
        if(Gdx.files.external("test.wav").exists()) {
        //  String ss = copySong(FILE);
            String songPath = Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath() + Gdx.files.external("test.wav").path();
            //System.out.println("B4: " + songPath);
            songPath.replace('\\', '/');
            //System.out.println("AF: " + songPath);
            song = minim.loadFile(songPath,2048);//"C:/users/seantest/test.wav", 2048);

        }

        String external = Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath();
        external.replace('\\', '/');

        Gdx.files.internal("data/audio/1.wav").copyTo(Gdx.files.external("1.wav"));
        Gdx.files.internal("data/audio/2.wav").copyTo(Gdx.files.external("2.wav"));
        Gdx.files.internal("data/audio/3.wav").copyTo(Gdx.files.external("3.wav"));
        Gdx.files.internal("data/audio/go.wav").copyTo(Gdx.files.external("go.wav"));
        count3 = minim.loadSample(external + "3.wav");
        count2 = minim.loadSample(external + "2.wav");
        count1 = minim.loadSample(external + "1.wav");
        countGo = minim.loadSample(external + "go.wav");

        audioData = new RSAudioData(this);

        if(song!=null){
            System.out.println("Song Info: " );
            System.out.println(song.length() + " " + song.sampleRate() + " " + song.bufferSize());
            beat = new BeatDetect(song.bufferSize(), song.sampleRate());
            beat.setSensitivity(300);  
            bl = new RSMBeatListener(beat, song); 
            fftLog = new FFT(song.bufferSize(), song.sampleRate());
            fftLog.logAverages(22, 3);
            max = new float[fftLog.avgSize()];
              for(int i = 0; i < max.length-1; i++)
                max[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public String copySong(String file) {
        externalFile = Gdx.files.external("test.wav");
        Gdx.files.internal(file).copyTo(externalFile);
        exFile = Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath() + "test.wav";
        System.out.println(exFile);
        return exFile;
    }

    public String sketchPath() {
        return Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath();
    }
```

Comment: you can try running it from a command prompt/terminal, to see if you get any exceptions.  `java -jar yourjarname.jar`

Comment: The first thing i would point out is that your string.replace function calls are doing nothing since they returned string is ignored. I think you want `external = external.replace('\\', '/');`

Comment: @DHall
firstly thank you, you legend! That is perfect, at least I can see the numbers now

@ gbtimmon 
thank you for pointing that out too! I've made those changes

The errors are seemingly from finding the audio samples, it cant find the .wavs

Answer (score 0):

Right click your Desktop Project->Build Path->Configure and check if in "Sources" is the android assets folder, and is checked in "Order and export".
Also when you are exporting your runnable jar, check "Package required libraries into generated library".