# Using png in a jar file

Tags: java, file, jar, png

When I run my jar file, i get a `javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!`

But the file **is** in the jar!

the code:

```
try {imgs.put("player1" , ImageIO.read(new File("/car1.png")));}
    catch (IOException e)   {System.out.println(e);}
```

I have tried to put `car1.png` everywhere in the jar file but its not working.

Comment: I don't know much about jars but your code there might be looking for `car1.png` in `/` instead of `/path/to/jar/car1.png` because your filename is "/car1.png", not "car1.png".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Swing: Displaying images from within a Jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127/java-swing-displaying-images-from-within-a-jar)

Comment: Please use the search before asking questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to do this instead.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("car1.png");
ImageIO.read(is);
```

Comment: "You probably want to do this instead."  Yes.  The basic problem with the OP's approach is that a File object cannot be established to a resource in a Jar file.  There is a variant of the command that returns an URL e.g. `URL urlToResource = getClass().getResource("car1.png");`.  Most methods that accept a File will also accept either an InputStream or URL.