# JRadioButtonMenuItem with a tick

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I am wondering if it's possible to change the default radio button menu item appearance in Java Swing.

By default a circle with a dot inside will indicate the selected state of the button, but i just want the good old fashioned tick next to a selected menu item and nothing to be shown next to an item that is not selected. (All items in question are of type `JRadioButtonMenuItem`)

I tried to use `.setSelectedIcon(...)` which can be found here :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelectedIcon(javax.swing.Icon)

But nothing changed, no exceptions thrown and im still stuck with the default appearance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a `JRadioButtonMenuItem`, you could use `JCheckBoxMenuItem` which has a tick mark by default. `JCheckBoxMenuItems` can also belong to a `ButtonGroup` also giving you single selection behavior shown by `JRadioButtonMenuItem`.

[Example](http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JMenuBar-Check-Box-Menu-Item-Test-Program.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Cann't we implement the same behaviour  with `JRadioButtonMenuItem`, as shown in your example by `JRadioButton`. Never tried it, though the idea presented by you looks encouraging.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, yes you can do it with radio buttons and that's what i have for now. the checkbox item is ok, but i am gonna wait to see if there is a way to put just a tick (with no box) before accepting your answer

Comment: @DanyKhalife I tested the `setSelectedIcon` on `JRadioButtonMenuItem` and did see the behavior (or lack of) you described. Thought this was a simpler solution :)

Comment: yea that's weird, the icon path should also be relative to the classpath correct? i agree, this does the trick for now :)

Comment: Yep, normally icon paths are read using `getResource()`. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127/java-swing-displaying-images-from-within-a-jar)