# java - Reading a image filepath that may change

Tags: java

I am creating a simple GUI using swing in Java and simply want to display a JPEG image as a banner in the frame.  I have the image working properly, but the filepath is subject to change as this will be sent to other people.  The image is stored in the folder I will be sending to others.  I am looking for a way to ensure that no matter what location the the folder has been moved to, the image will display.  I am new to this site, and fairly new to Java. Thanks for you help in advance.

Relevant Code:

```
ImageIcon numberImage = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\numberGame\\numbers.jpg");
Image image = numberImage.getImage();
Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(300,120,java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
numberImage = new ImageIcon(newimg);
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel("", numberImage, JLabel.CENTER);
JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

imagePanel.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

Comment: Put the image into your classpath, then it's going to be always available via a `"classpath:/package/name/file.jpg"` path. You may want to look into maven for building your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Swing: Displaying images from within a Jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127/java-swing-displaying-images-from-within-a-jar)

Comment: @nhouser9 but if the program is not inside a Jar, specifying a relative path should just work for this problem. I think if it's not a Jar the solution is pretty much simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure, the image could be displayed in every context, you must specify a relative path instead of an absolute path.

You could change:

```
ImageIcon numberImage = new ImageIcon("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\numberGame\numbers.jpg");
```

To:

```
ImageIcon numberImage = new ImageIcon("numbers.jpg");
```

And this should work in other contexts (with other different paths).
Or if the image is in a directory inside your program put *"\imageFolder\numbers.jpg"*.

This should work, the main change is to replace the absolute path with a relative path.

Comment: In all my searching I hadn't seen a solution as easy as this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a relative path instead of absolute. Here's a quick explanation that's pretty clear.

http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-relative-and-canonical-path-of-file-or-directory/60

Good luck. :)