# Files not found after packing everything up to a Jar-File, though its working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, project-structure

So my program is finally done in it's first version. I can run it in Eclipse IDE without any problems, but as soon as I pack it up into a Jar-File, it can't find the files that were in a folder within the project (declared as source folder). I already know, that while compiling, the folder structure changes and I tried working around that, but it doesn't work and I don't want to stick to such a work-around.
Project structure:

```
- src/main/java/
    + [my packages]
- resources/
     + configs/[some files]
     + languages/[some language files]
     + levelcards/[some images]
```

In my program im accessing i.e. the files inside "configs" with

```
new File("./resources/configs/[...]");
```

and it works absolutely fine, as the folder exists in the project. After compiling it doesn't though, so I tried it with

```
new File("./configs/[...]");
```

but it doesn't work either.
What I expect is it working regardless of me launching it in Eclipse or via the JRE directly, though I have no idea how to get it to that point. If you can help me out in any way, I would appreciate it!
Gregor

Comment: Objects in a Jar are not files and you can't use file based APIs to access them. Look at Class.getResource / getResourceAsStream

Comment: See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31127/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 What I do not understand while using this is the file structure this method is assuming... If I say "Class.getResource("Test.properties")", where does Test.properties have to be located?

Comment: See the answers in the question I linked

Comment: @greg-449 I didn't see this one, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

eg:

Assume have a Utility class which will read from file and return as String

```
class Utils{

public static String readFromFile(String filePath){
  InputStream inputStream=Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(filePath); //eg:- configs/temp_file.txt
/* Now once you get the InputStream there 
are lot of utility library to return as string */

String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
 for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
     if (result.length() > 0) {
         result.append(newLine);
     }
     result.append(line);
 }
 return result.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Yes! I understand your solution, but I'm not reading certain lines, but I'm using the "Properties" class. Depending on the case, I'm also using the "Properties" class to write to those files. Is there any way you could adapt your solution to this?
Edit: I already changed my project structure for it to work with "Class.getResource()", but now I'm getting a FileNotFound-Error, so this case is still open. I uploaded the class on pastebin, so you can have a look into it: https://pastebin.com/aGFPhjnB